# How can I quickly load data using Linq to SQL into C# Lists of corresponding objects?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, database-performance

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database which stores the data for web and mobile applications, and for which I have a handy management desktop program written in WPF which gets data using Linq to SQL.

The database is on a remote server, and speed with Linq to SQL to load data or do complex operations can be a big problem. (It's taking over half an hour to load my data even in the middle of the night on New Year's Eve, while today it is taking well over an hour, and I only have about 30 tables, 10-20 rows per table, and even the largest tables are only like 18,000 rows, most are only 10's or 100's of rows.) Edit: Yesterday something was slowing it down to 1-3 hours per load, whereas this morning it loaded in 23 minutes.

The management program can do many complex operations quickly, but it manages this by loading most of the data into copies in local memory, so I can do logic locally in C# and not have to communicate with the database unless I need to update or change data. So I load C# lists with objects that contain all the data members that the Linq to SQL classes have, but are not linked to the database, with many nice helper functions and cross-references in C#.

That works really well, except that loading the database data in the first place takes a problematically long time, and I wonder if there isn't a faster way.

I end up doing something like this:

```
foreach (Blue_Member mem in App.db.Blue_Members)
{
    Members.Add(new Local_Blue_Member(mem));
}
```

Where Local_Blue_Member is not a Linq-to-SQL class, but has a constructor which takes one and copies all the values of its data.

I have also been having some classes do SQL queries to find related data and store it in local lists where useful, but I expect that is multiplying the number of SQL calls, so I am working on breaking that out.

I wonder though if there is anything else I might do to more quickly load all the data from tables. Such as, maybe there is a way to ask for a batch table load, or a way to say I want to load it read-only, that will improve speed on the load?

Comment: `Members = App.db.Blue_Members.ToList();`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I can't remember the last time I was so psyched to try a single line of code!

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Hmm. If that sped it up, I can't tell. I think maybe my connection is especially bad today, as it took two hours to load the last time, and even having converted most things to load as you suggested, it looks about on track for the same this time.

Comment: See following webpage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx.  SQLCMD and BCP are designed to archive a SQL Server and arre designed to be 100x more efficient than the C# interface. I have an application that I use in C# which creates a process which launches the sqlcmd.exe to create a CSV file and then I read the CSV into my application.  Works greater and speed is much faster than performing same query inside a C# application.  In my case I get a 10MB csv file.  I'm using SQL Standard on a very large database an it takes 30 minutes to run while doing same in C# alone 1/2 day.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks! I will check that out. Ya I was starting to think of things like "make a DB backup and download that... then load the DB backup on the machine running the program" but ... ya.

Comment: Maybe you should have a local database that *synchronizes* with the remote database instead of fetching all data each time.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, that's a good idea too.